# Ошибка PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required на php7.0 yii2

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2

На хостинге работало все нормально,как только перенес на vps ошибка. логи тут -

```
[php7:warn] [pid 31677] [client 87.236.22.33:41104] PHP Warning:  require(/home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66



[php7:error] [pid 31677] [client 87.236.22.33:41104] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Comment: `composer require symfony/polyfill-mbstring`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Проблема была в правах. теперь ошибка Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved

Comment: В php 7 слово Object зарезервировано и его нельзя использовать как имя класса. Вам надо обновить yii на php 5.6, а потом уже поднимать версию пхп.